# UISwitches, need an explanation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiswitch

How do the switches work in XCode4? how do i check which properties are available to me for the switches? 
i am trying to check the state of a switch and make a label change according to the state. Something like this:

```
-(IBAction)clickedOnSwitch:(id)sender {
    NSString *switchState = [[NSString alloc]init];
    if (mySwitchIsOn) {
        switchState = @"switch is On";
    }
    else
    {
    switchState = @"switch is Off";        
    }

    myLabel.text = switchState;
    [switchState release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [UISwitch](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference either on the web or in the Xcode documentation browser.

Comment: Also the code provided leaks an NSString instance on every call. Think about what your assignments ("=") do to your retain/release pair.

Comment: hey Jonah, good catch on the memory leak but its actually being released in a different area. should it be released here instead of elsewhere?

Comment: Your alloc/init is completely wrong, for starters. You're allocating an empty string and then promptly reassigning its pointer to something else.